# How to test POST method using DRF and HyperlinkedModelSerializer serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework (DRF), and I am trying to test a POST method.

These are my models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
        verbose_name = 'user'


class Brand(Group):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='%(class)ss',
                              related_query_name='%(class)s')
    description = models.TextField('description', max_length=3000, blank=True)
    facebook_url = models.URLField('facebook url', blank=True)
    twitter_url = models.URLField('twitter url', blank=True)
    instagram_url = models.URLField('instagram url', blank=True)
    pinterest_url = models.URLField('pinterest url', blank=True)
    portfolio_url = models.URLField('portfolio url',  blank=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField('phone number', blank=True)
```

These are my serializers:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    brands = HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='brand-detail'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
            'url',
            'username',
            'email',
            'brands',
        )

class BrandSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    addresses = HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,
                                        read_only=True,
                                        view_name='address-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = (
            'url',
            'name',
            'owner',
            'description',
            'facebook_url',
            'twitter_url',
            'instagram_url',
            'pinterest_url',
            'portfolio_url',
            'phone_number',
        )
```

These are my views:

```
class CustomUserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """"A view set for viewing and editing custom users."""
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer


class BrandViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """A view set for viewing and editing brands."""
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BrandSerializer
```

And this is my test, I am using pytest:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_brand_with_valid_data(client):
    """Tests POST method with valid data to create a Brand instance."""
    user = CustomUser.objects.create(username='x',
                                     email='x@example.com',
                                     password='abc123', )

    data = {
        'owner': f'http://testserver/api/users/{user.id}/',
        'name': 'NA',
    }

    print(data)

    response = client.post(reverse('address-list'),
                           data=json.dumps(data),
                           content_type='application/json')

    assert response.status_code == HTTP_201_CREATED
```

Instead of a 201 response, I am getting a 400, so I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

**Traceback:**

```
_________________________________________________________________________________ test_create_brand_with_valid_data _________________________________________________________________________________

client = <django.test.client.Client object at 0x10c2199b0>

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_create_brand_with_valid_data(client):
        """Tests POST method with valid data to create a Brand instance."""
        user = CustomUser.objects.create(username='x',
                                         email='x@example.com',
                                         password='abc123', )

        data = {
            'owner': f'http://testserver/api/users/{user.id}/',
            'name': 'NA',
        }

        print(data)

        response = client.post(reverse('address-list'),
                               data=json.dumps(data),
                               content_type='application/json')

>       assert response.status_code == HTTP_201_CREATED
E       assert 400 == 201
E        +  where 400 = <Response status_code=400, "application/json">.status_code

api/tests/test_brand.py:98: AssertionError
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace? Do you perhaps need a `null=True` for all fields where you have `blank=True` in your `Brand` model because you're not supplying those fields in your POST request.

Comment: @slider, I just added the traceback.

Comment: That doesn't seem very helpful. Did you try `null = True` in the model fields?

Comment: @slider, actually I need `owner` to be mandatory, and I think if I change that constrain it will work but this parameter is required.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean `owner`. I meant all fields for which you have `blank=True`.

Comment: @slider, honestly, I think the problem is the `owner` field, and I don't how how to pass it. I am able to create a brand using the admin interface of DRF, but I cannot use nested dictionaries in the test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184159/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-slider).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite embarrassing, so the problem was that I am requesting to the wrong endpoint. The following code solves my problem, and it also avoids hard-coding the url:

```
import json
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.status import (HTTP_200_OK,
                                   HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                                   HTTP_201_CREATED,
                                   HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                                   HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_brand_with_valid_data(client):
    """Tests POST method with valid data to create a Brand instance."""
    user = CustomUser.objects.create(username='x',
                                     email='x@example.com',
                                     password='abc123', )
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request = factory.get('/')

    context = {'request': Request(request)}
    user_serializer = CustomUserSerializer(user, context=context)

    data = {
        'owner': user_serializer.data['url'],
        'name': 'NA',
    }

    response = client.post(reverse('brand-list'),
                           data=json.dumps(data),
                           content_type='application/json')

    assert response.status_code == HTTP_201_CREATED
```

This test worked like a charm.